# Determing Fourier series and what it converges to

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I am trying to determine the fourier series of $f(x)$ on $[-2,2]$ which I believe I have done correctly. I will show some details below of my calculation. However my question is how do I determine what the Fourier series of $f(x)$ on $[-2,2]$ converges to. My guess is that you must take the limit of $f(x)$, but do I take the limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$? However there is parts if the equation that are $(-1)^n$which confuses me if I was to take the limit.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
2,&-2\leq x \leq 0\\
x, &0 < x \leq 2\\
\end{cases}$$

So I know that,

$$f(x) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big) +  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)$$

Then calculating $A_0,$

$$A_0 = \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int _{-2}^{2} f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2} \Bigg [\int_{-2}^02dx + \int_0^{2} x \Bigg]= \frac{1}{2}[4+2] = 3 $$

Then calculating $A_n$,

$$A_n = \frac{1}{L}\int_{-2}^{2} f(x) \cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2} \Big) = \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\int_{-2}^0 2\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\Big) + \int _0^2 x\cos \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\Big) \Bigg]\\ = \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 }(-1)^{n} - \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 }$$

Then calculating $B_n, $

$$B_n = \frac{1}{L}\int_{-2}^{2} f(x) \sin\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2} \Big) = \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\int_{-2}^0 2\sin\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\Big) + \int _0^2 x\sin \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\Big) \Bigg]\\ = \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\frac{-4}{n\pi}\cos \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\Big)\Big|_{-2}^0 \Bigg] + \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\frac{-2x}{\pi n}\cos \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2 }\Big) + \frac{4}{n^2\pi ^2}\sin \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2 }\Big)\Big|_0^2 \Bigg] \\ = \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\frac{-4}{\pi n } + \frac{4}{\pi n } \cos(\pi n )\Bigg] + \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\frac{-4}{\pi n }\cos(\pi n) + \frac{4}{\pi ^2 n ^2  } \sin (\pi n) \Bigg] \\ = \frac{1}{2} \Bigg[\frac{-4}{n\pi} + \frac{4}{n\pi}(-1)^n - \frac{4}{\pi n}(-1)^n \Bigg] = \frac{-2}{n\pi}$$

Thus,

$$f(x) = \frac{3}{2}+  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigg[\frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 }(-1)^{n} - \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 }\Bigg] \cos\frac{n\pi x}{2}  + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigg[\frac{-2}{n\pi }\Bigg] \sin \frac{n\pi x}{2}$$

So again my thought would be to take the limit of this function, and I have a feeling that it approaches $\frac{3}{2}$. But I am not sure if this is correct or how to show it, looking for some help with this, thanks!

Comment: Fourier Series is for a periodic signal, which in your case is a repeated version of $f(x) \in [-2,2]$

Comment: so how does this help me see what it converges to?

Comment: Well, at first your $B_n$ is true and $0<\frac32<2$ then $f\to\dfrac32$

Comment: @MyGlasses thanks again for your help!

Comment: so I do not need to take the limit of this function?

Comment: We know the Fourier series of a piecewise function is converges to function in all continuous points and for other points it is $f(x)=\dfrac{f(x+)+f(x-)}{2}$.

Comment: so do I need to use that formula or just say what you have said up above? seemed like a small explanation

Comment: This is a theorem and for someone who knows that it's sufficient!

Comment: could you use that formula to show an explanation of it? that will my last question

Comment: It's my pleasant, but explanation of what? you mean the theorem.

Comment: yeah how could I use that theorem to show what it converges to

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence and http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ConvergenceFourierSeries.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f (x) $ is piecewise smooth. But has a jump discontinuity at $x=0$ , the Fourier series will converge to $$1/2[ f (0-)+f (0+)]$$.

You don't need to calculate the series to find wheter it converges or not.

You can read more about it at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ConvergenceFourierSeries.aspx

Comment: so then this series converges to $1/2[ f (0-)+f (0+)] = \frac{1}{2}[2-0] = 1$?

Comment: Correct! I had a similar question on my exam last week. I was first considering doing it the way you tried in the question, but then I realized I had to use this neat and nice theorem.

Comment: a user above said $0<\frac{3}{2}<2$ so then $f$ goes to $\frac{3}{2}$ so which method would be correct?